# navigating to a new page on clicking an item in the listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am building an app where i need to navigate to another page on clicking an item in the listbox. I have tried a lot but was not able to do it. When clicked nothing happens. Please see my xaml and cs file and check if there is any problem in my coding.

My xaml is:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged"  Height="676" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <Button>
                 <Button.Content>
                   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80" Width="400">
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                           <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" Height="80" Width="120"/>
                           <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                               <!-- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>-->
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </StackPanel>
                   </ScrollViewer>
               </Button.Content>
           </Button>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My cs file is:

```
private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing

    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    // Navigate to the new page
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsDetails.xaml?selectedItem=" + listBox1.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

    // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: I think you can add property of IsHitTestVisible="False" to Button. So the listBox1_SelectionChanged method can be excuted.

Comment: why are you putting all this stuff within button content

Comment: remove once this selection changed event from xaml and further add this event...try this it could help you

Comment: @PradeepKesharwani it worked. i have set the  IsHitTestVisible="False"

Comment: @PradeepKesharwani if i would have removed button.content then also it didnt work. Anywys placing it was useless. But i need to set that property

Comment: @ChrisShao I have another problem. Actually in the page that i am navigated to on clicking an item in the listbox in that page i want to show complete details of the item clicked? How can i achieve this? should i post my code so that you can help?

Comment: I think you can transmit a key as parameter to navigated page and make your datasource availble on navigated page. On navigated page, get data from datasource by this key, and show it.

Comment: can u please help me with codes i m very new to both c# and windows phone environment. I shall post my code if you want to have a look

Comment: Sorry, I am on my phone and I can't read your code now. you can read this link, it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234765/silverlight-listbox-navigation-to-new-page-with-object-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add property of IsHitTestVisible="False" to Button. So the listBox1_SelectionChanged method can be excuted.